# Is there is exists dataset contains images labels/classes from some social network like Instagram?

Tags: data-request

I'm doing a recommender for one social network disabled yet.

Social network includes images post, like in Instagram. My idea is scrap images labels/classes and then try to classify it in some given classes. However since social network disabled, there are a few data for handling this task and I'm searching some opened dataset of network images labels.

Maybe you know some? Or I could do scrapping by myself from Instagram? How to do it exactly?